# Python: Keras model returns different results for the same data and same model

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, image-classification

Last few hours, I have been trying to make my first model for image classification. For this purpose, I have used [Image classification from scratch](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/) tutorial. As I followed the steps I managed to reach the end of the tutorial.

The only differences I made compared to the code in tutorial are:

- in order to make training process faster, I changed number of epochs from 50 to 10,
- I deleted *Image augmentation block* from `make_model` function (one row of code).

Now, I am getting to what my problem is. At the end, when I try to get the prediction results for the same data and the same model again, the results are different. Look at this simple code:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     predictions = model.predict(val_ds)
...     predictions_list = [round(pred[0], 3) for pred in predictions]
...     print(predictions_list[:10])
```

and the result:

```
[0.937, 0.905, 1.0, 0.094, 0.021, 0.095, 0.07, 0.006, 1.0, 1.0]
[0.905, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.122, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[0.996, 0.003, 1.0, 0.887, 1.0, 1.0, 0.798, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 0.819, 0.999, 1.0, 0.887, 0.087, 1.0, 0.914, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.916, 0.102]
```

I assume, that results can be different only in case I retrain the model. But that is not my case! I only rerun `.predict()` method. So, my question is - can you help me, what I am doing wrong, please? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to pick one of the images from your data set and give it to your model for several times. look if the outputs differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with reading data function [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory), which has got its `shuffle` argument set to `True`.

When I reload the data again and set `shuffle=False` like this:

```
>>> val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
...     'PetImages',
...     shuffle=False,
...     validation_split=0.2,
...     subset="validation",
...     seed=1337,
...     image_size=image_size,
...     batch_size=batch_size,
... )
>>> for i in range(5):
...     predictions = model.predict(val_ds)
...     predictions_list = [round(pred[0], 3) for pred in predictions]
...     print(predictions_list[:10])
```

then the result looks as I expected:

```
[0.998, 0.994, 1.0, 1.0, 0.885, 1.0, 0.998, 1.0, 0.979, 1.0]
[0.998, 0.994, 1.0, 1.0, 0.885, 1.0, 0.998, 1.0, 0.979, 1.0]
[0.998, 0.994, 1.0, 1.0, 0.885, 1.0, 0.998, 1.0, 0.979, 1.0]
[0.998, 0.994, 1.0, 1.0, 0.885, 1.0, 0.998, 1.0, 0.979, 1.0]
[0.998, 0.994, 1.0, 1.0, 0.885, 1.0, 0.998, 1.0, 0.979, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the code below, please?

```
>>> val_item = val_ds.take(1)
>>> for i in range(5):
...     predictions = model.predict(val_item)
...     predictions_list = [round(pred[0], 3) for pred in predictions]
...     print(predictions_list[:10])
```

In your code, you are using different items not the same one. You can check it by manually printing the val_ds value.

Comment: The code you sent prints out the different results again, so it does not work. When I print out `val_ds`, it returns the following: `<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 180, 180, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>`.

Comment: Also when I print out the whole `predictions_list`, it has got 32 items. However, I would expect only 1 because of `val_item = val_ds.take(1)` part.

Comment: You need to set `batch_size = 1` to take only 1 item. You are working on batches.